# A density problem in Sobolev space?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

For $ k,p \in \mathbb{N} $, denote $ k $ order classical Sobolev space on $ (0,2\pi) $ by $ H^k(0,2\pi) $ and define
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}^{k+p}_0:= \{ \varphi \in H^{k+p}(0,2\pi): \varphi(0) = \cdots = \varphi^{(p-1)}(0) = 0 \}.
\end{equation*}

> What is the closure of $ \mathcal{H}^{k+p}_0 $ in $ H^k(0,2\pi) $, if
>   the former is dense in the latter?

Answer (score 0):

When $ k = 0 $, since 
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}^p_0 = \{ \varphi \in H^p(0,2\pi): \varphi(0) = \cdots = \varphi^{(p-1)}(0) = 0\}
\end{equation*}
and thus, $ C^\infty_0 (0,2\pi) \subseteq \mathcal{H}^p_0 $, we have 
\begin{equation*}
L^2(0,2\pi) \subseteq \overline{C^\infty_0 (0,2\pi)} \subseteq 
\overline{\mathcal{H}^p_0} \subseteq L^2(0,2\pi)
\end{equation*}
In the case $ k = 0 $, we have the former $  \mathcal{H}^p_0 $ dense in the latter $ L^2(0,2\pi) $.

However, for $ 0 \neq k \geq p $, the assertion is wrong. Similar to above deduction, we can see that $ \overline{\mathcal{H}^{k+p}_0 } = \mathcal{H}^k_0 $ in $ H^k(0,2\pi) $.

Notice that the case $ k < p $ is still open!